# How to remove <li>`s output, that starts from 768px width in middle-state of bootstrap menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Developing responsive design, using bootstrap 3, met next problem:

1. On 767px BS menu looks good, but on 768px I see content of menu, that used to be hidden in "hamburger", over BS menu container.
2. And "hamburger" is hidden now.

[good(767px width)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJzFC.png)

[bad(768px width)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ybIs.png)

Is there any good solution for still showing "mobile" menu type on "tablet" display width ?

Comment: Please give your code to get solution.

Comment: here is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/dmitry_rasko/gf941p3u/) sorry, if too huge